# How to update bindings library to prevent developers needing a proguard file?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, linker

As you can see [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/StoreReviewPlugin/issues/6), we implemented the in-app review feature on Android, but when a developer changes the Linker to Link All and Shrinker to r8, we get a crash. The error message is as follows:

```
Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Lcom/google/android/play/core/review/c;.requestReviewFlow()Lcom/google/android/play/core/tasks/Task;"
```

I was able to still use r8, d8 and Link All by adding these to a proguard.cfg file in an Android [sample project](https://github.com/PatGet/XamarinPlayCoreUpdater/pull/10), whose build action set to the proguard build config:

```
-keep class com.google.android.play.core.review.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.play.core.tasks.** { *; }
```

Is there a way to edit [the bindings library](https://github.com/PatGet/XamarinPlayCoreUpdater) that will prevent this issue from happening, so that users don't have to add this to their proguard?

Comment: On GitHub, jamesmontemagno said he would check. Let's follow this issue on GitHub.

Comment: He did? This is a generic question for libraries though